# RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required Realm, while adding new table on existing database, Android

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I am using Realm gradle version "3.0.0", I have two table "Word" & "Favourite" like below

[image]

Now I want to add third Table named "History"

for that i have done below code

```
@Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        final RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            RealmObjectSchema wordSchema = schema.get("Word");
            wordSchema.addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_PRONOUCE, String.class);
            wordSchema.addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, String.class);
            oldVersion++;
        } if(oldVersion == 1){
            RealmObjectSchema favouriteSchema = schema.get("Favourite");
            favouriteSchema.addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID, String.class);
            favouriteSchema.addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_WORD, String.class);
            favouriteSchema.addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_OBJECT_ID, String.class);
            favouriteSchema.addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_PRONOUCE, String.class);
            favouriteSchema.addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, String.class);
            favouriteSchema.addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_MEANING, String.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }
         if(oldVersion == 2){
                schema.create("History")
                .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID, String.class)
                .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_WORD, String.class)
                .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_OBJECT_ID, String.class)
                .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_PRONOUCE, String.class)
                .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, String.class)
                .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_MEANING, String.class);
                oldVersion++;
            }
    }
```

But I am getting below error,

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
    - Property 'History.id' has been changed from 'string' to 'int'.
    - Property 'History.word' has been made required.
    - Property 'History.objectId' has been made required.
    - Property 'History.pronunciation' has been made required.
    - Property 'History.type' has been made required.
    - Property 'History.meaning' has been made required.
```

I have not created any History table before, than why it is saying History.id has been changed from 'string' to 'int'?

How to add History table properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     if(oldVersion == 2){
            schema.create("History")
            .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ID, int.class)
            .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_WORD, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
            .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_OBJECT_ID, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
            .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_PRONOUCE, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
            .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
            .addField(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME_MEANING, String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
            oldVersion++;
        }
```

On your test phone, just uninstall/reinstall the app afterwards, or you'll need to bump the schema version and change the fields to the right type.

Comment: Technically I can write the required migration for `oldVersion == 3` if it's that messed up, but it's trickier because you have to change PK type.

Comment: Thanks alot you have saved my lots of time

Comment: In document also I am unable to find proper information of this adding new table

Comment: They do have it in their [examples](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/581c2a9fb2560c0e850549a91bb561346c66a83c/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java#L93-L95)

Comment: I thought they would create new table automatically, it did work like this before. Since when we need to create new table schema by ourself?